# how to compare equals and less than today's date to a given date in mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp, date

How can I compare (equals and less than) today's date to a given date in MYSQL ? I am getting problems when using `<=`. This is not working when I use `=`. I want both less than and equal.

```
   <%
   rs=st.executeQuery("select approcode,approemail,appromon,approvemon,approtue,approvetue,approwed,approvewed,approthr,approvethr,approfri,approvefri,approsat,approvesat,commen,months,SUM(nol) from `pushkalit`.`approval`WHERE (CONVERT( `approcode` USING utf8 ) LIKE '%"+user+"%')  
  AND DATE( NOW( ) ) <= DATE( appromon ) OR
      DATE( NOW( ) ) <= DATE( approtue ) OR
      DATE( NOW( ) ) <= DATE( approwed ) OR 
      DATE( NOW( ) ) <= DATE( approthr ) OR
      DATE( NOW( ) ) <= DATE( approfri ) OR
      DATE( NOW( ) ) <= DATE( approvesat )");
     %>
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong direction, you're currently doing equals and MORE than today date. It should be `NOW( ) >= DATE(....`

Answer (score 0):

*if i understand correctly you should do some change like:* `now()>=date()`

```
DATE( NOW( ) ) >= DATE( appromon )
```

*sample* [***sqlfiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/486f9/3)